# Google Apps and BPOS on the same domain

Tags: bpos

We are currently using Google Apps for email. Since contact sync and calendar is not ideal we intend to migrate part/all of the organization to BPOS.

My MX records point to Google Apps. Is there a way for the same domain to use Google Apps for several accounts and BPOS for the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could feasibly set up an SMTP relay for your domain, change the MX to that, and forward messages on to the appropriate 'real' SMTP server based on the target address.

You would also have to ensure that BPOS and Gmail didn't assume that they were responsible for the whole domain, and hence incorrectly try to route mail internally to boxes on your domain.